# Linear transformation of a triangle is still a triangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Let $f$ be the function that maps each point $(x, y, z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $x \neq 0$ to the unique point in the plane $$P := \{(1, y, z)\,\mid\,|y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ such that $\{x, f(x)\}$ is linearly dependent.

So I got $f(x,y,z) = (1,y/x,z/x)$ and found the image of the corners; how do I know a point inside the domain triangle is in the triangle of the codomain?

Comment: Strange title. $f$ is not a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{ty_1+(1-t)y_2}{tx_1+(1-t)x_2}
=\frac{tx_1}{tx_1+(1-t)x_2}\frac{y_1}{x_1}
+\frac{(1-t)x_2}{tx_1+(1-t)x_2}\frac{y_2}{x_2}.
$$